# 'gulp' is not recognized as an internal or external command

Tags: node.js, gulp

I am trying to use [Gulp](http://gulpjs.com/) and [Node.Js](https://nodejs.org/en/) to stream my process for minifying and concatenating CSS/JS files for production.

Here is what I have done.

1. I installed [Node.Js](https://nodejs.org/en/) on my Windows 7 machine.
2. Installed Gulp globally using this command `npm install -g gulp`
3. Then I added a new User variable called `NODE_PATH` set it to `%AppData%\npm\node_modules`

After closing and re-opening my command line, I tried to run a gulp task from the command line (i.e. `gulp css`). But that give me the following error

```
'gulp' is not recognized as an internal or external command
```

How can I get this to work?

When I opened the following path using the search bar in windows, 
`%AppData%\npm\node_modules` I see the following two folders

```
gulp
gulp-cli
```

[image]

I've tried to add `%AppData%\npm\node_modules` to the `Path` variable on my system variable, but it did not take it because that variable reached it's max allowed character limit.

I removed couple of paths from my `Path` variable and added `;C:\Users\[MyWindowsUserName]\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules`

but still not working.

I even tried to set the path at run time using this command

`PATH=%PATH%;C:\Users\[MyWindowsUserName]\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules`
then run `gulp` and still the same issues.

What am I missing here? What else do I need in order to get this to work?

Comment: When you echo $NODE_PATH do you get the correct path to the global node dependencies?

Comment: when I type `echo $NODE_PATH` from the command line, it returns `$NODE_PATH`

Comment: Sorry didn't read you were on win7. Try echo %PATH%

Comment: And echo %NODE_PATH%

Comment: typing `echo %NODE_PATH%` printed this `%AppData%\npm\node_modules`

Comment: And can you confirm that inside that folder (\npm\node_modules) there is gulp's folder?

Comment: yes. I just added a screenshot of what is in that folder

Comment: Okey maybe you could try the path manually. Going to My PC, right click -> properties -> Advanced settings -> environment variables. Then just add the new path to your users global path variable. It should work now.

Comment: still now working

Comment: Well the last thing I can think of is v

Comment: Not sure that I follow you. What is v?

Comment: Did you restart windows (or just explorer)?

Comment: I restarted my entire machine also but still not working

Comment: Do you have a `gulp.cmd` and `gulp` file in the Roaming\npm directory? I don't have any environment vars for gulp on my machine and gulp is working fine

Comment: Have you tried to reinstall it? `npm uninstall -g gulp`

Answer (score 72, accepted):

I solved the problem by uninstalling NodeJs and gulp then re-installing both again.

To install gulp globally I executed the following command

```
npm install -g gulp
```

Comment: To uninstall gulp using the follow command npm uninstall -g gulp.  Then if you Windows, go to uninstall programs from the control panel and uninstall nodejs

Comment: you don't have to uninstall anything. `npm install -g gulp` works like charm.

Comment: Even after running this command, when I try gulp build, it gives me "'gulp' is not recognized as an internal or external command"

Comment: Ran into this issue today. In my case, the problem is the mode I open the Visual Studio. I opened it in Administrator mode but then gulp was installed for my login (user) account. While the npm is added to the PATH environment variable, it is pointing to the user account which Administrator mode was unable to accesss. Once I re-installed gulp globally with `-g`, I was able to open the Gulp tasks as expected.

Comment: This worked great!  Did not have to uninstall locally for me.

Comment: Worked like charm!

Answer (score 143):

I had similar issue when I installed locally initially(w/o -g). I reinstalled with -g (global) and then it worked.

```
npm install -g gulp
```

you should run gulp from folder where `gulpfile.js` is available.

Comment: I still have the same issue even if I am in the npm folder, it's quite weird, the batch file glup.cmd is well in the folder.  i am under Windows 10 21H1 and NodeJs 16.3

Answer (score 25):

Go to `My Computer>Properties>Advance System Settings>Environment Variables>`

Under the variables of Administrator edit the PATH variable & change its value to `"C:\Users\Username\AppData\Roaming\npm"`. Note: The username in the path will be the current Admin user's name that you have logged in with.

Comment: I solved this by editing the user path, since the %AppData%\npm is in the user directory (Windows Server 2016 Standard).

Answer (score 7):

I had the same problem on windows 7. You must edit your path system variable manually.

Go to START -> edit the system environment variables -> Environment variables -> in system part find variables "Path" -> edit -> add new path after ";" to your file gulp.cmd directory some like ';C:\Users\YOURUSERNAME\AppData\Roaming\npm' -> click ok and close these windows -> restart your CLI -> enjoy

Comment: Only solution that worked for me, on Windows 10, node-v10.16.3-x64, Visual Studio 2015. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 5):

You may need to install the `gulp-cli` globally. Uninstall then re-install if you already have it:

`npm uninstall -g gulp-cli`

`npm install -g gulp-cli`

Answer (score 0):

Sorry that was a typo. You can either add node_modules to the end of your user's global path variable, or maybe check the permissions associated with that folder (node _modules). The error doesn't seem like the last case, but I've encountered problems similar to yours. I find the first solution enough for most cases. Just go to environment variables and add the path to node_modules to the last part of your user's path variable. Note I'm saying user and not system.

Just add a semicolon to the end of the variable declaration and add the static path to your node_module folder. ( Ex c:\path\to\node_module)

Alternatively you could:

In your CMD

```
PATH=%PATH%;C:\\path\to\node_module
```

**EDIT**

The last solution will work as long as you don't close your CMD. So, use the first solution for a permanent change.

Comment: nothing is working for me. I even took the full path and added it to the system `Path` variable and that did not work

Answer (score 0):

In my case, this problem occured because I did `npm install` with another system user in my project folder before. Gulp was already installed globally. After deleting folder */node_modules/* in my project, and running `npm install` with the current user, it worked.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure, when you run command (install npm -g gulp), it will create install gulp on C:\ directory.

that directory should match with whatver npm path variable set in your java path.

just run path from command prompt, and verify this. if not, change your java class path variable wherever you gulp is instaled.

It should work.

Answer (score 0):

If you have mysql install in your windows 10 try uninstall every myqsl app from your computer. Its work for me. exactly when i installed the mysql in my computer gulp command and some other commands stop working and then i have tried everything but not nothing worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I just encountered this on Windows 10 and the latest NodeJS (14.15.1).  In my case our admins have our profiles and true "home" folder remotely mount onto our work machine(s).  Npm wanted to put its cache over on the remote server and that has worked until this release.

I was unaware that npm has a `.npmrc` file available.  I added one to my actual machine's `C:\Users\my-id` folder and it contains:

```
prefix=C:\Users\my-id\nodejs\npm
cache=c:\Users\my-id\nodejs\npm-cache
```

I also added these paths to my `PATH` environment variable.

I went to the `APPDATA` folder on my work machine and the remote "home" server and deleted all the npm related Roaming folders.  I deleted the `node_modules` folder in my project.

I closed all open windows and reopened them.  I brought up a command prompt in my project dir and re `init`ed npm and reinstalled the modules I wanted.

After that everything is rolling along.

Answer (score 0):

Just to add to @Vinod R's answer

Go to My Computer>Properties>Advance System Settings>Environment Variables>

Under the variables of Administrator edit the PATH variable & change its value to "C:\Users\Username\AppData\Roaming\npm". Note: The username in the path will be the current Admin user's name that you have logged in with.

After this, move the path to the top as shown in the image attached.

[image for demostration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LuXfu.png)

Answer (score -1):

I was having the same exception with node v12.13.1,

**Downgraded** node to v10.15.3 and it works fine now.

Answer (score -2):

The best solution, you can manage the multiple node versions using nvm installer. then, install the required node's version using below command

```
nvm install version
```

Use below command as a working node with mentioned version alone

```
nvm use version
```

now, you can use any version node without uninstalling previous installed node.